# How to make a iPhone tester in my site to report if sites are mobile adapted

Tags: iphone, web

I would like to make a section on my site where users can test if their websites are mobile adapted.
Is any way to do that? I see a lot of sites in the net but I don't like to frame it, I'd like make my own.

---

Mmmm... the trouble is that link, shows me how can mobilize my site, but what I want to make, is a php/html section of my joomla, where users can input their webs, and shows if are adapted.

Something like this: [www.iphonetester.com](http://www.iphonetester.com)

But, that site, doesn't use the user agent, so, if you put http://www.kalyma.com.ar shows desktop version, instead of showing http://m.kalyma.com.ar which is the mobile version. (this is because I have a plugin which redirects the site based on user agent!)

Comment: Without knowing much about the processes, I'm guessing you'll have to make some sort of proxy service which spoofs the useragent of the client's browser in order to make it appear to the server as a request made from a mobile browser.

Comment: Any clue about this stuff? Seems to be the answer, but I don't know how make it. Thanks.

Comment: the website you posted (iphonetester.com) tells you how it works: "**How is this a test?** *The screen dimensions of an iPhone are the same as this test frame. The exterior look and feel are similar to a real iPhone.*" So all it is is literally an iframe surrounded by a picture of an iphone! Thats why it doesn't redirect to mobile sites. It even tells you to use safari because that will make it more realistic (mobile safari ~= desktop safari).
"

Comment: I know, that's the reason of my question. Is any way to make of add user-agents to that iframe? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks too much for the answers!!! I will try the solution by @ThomasClayson Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right... the only way I can think of (and this is untested...)

You need to curl the content of the page that someone's trying to access and set the useragent as such:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3');
```

Then you can output the html into a div on your page using jquery's `load()` function or similar.

You'll have to look into how to properly do it though, because you're downloading onto your web server any non-absolute links will have to have the base url set properly so images and other things work properly.

That's the only way I can think you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me google that for you :

http://shaunmackey.com/articles/mobile/php-auto-bowser-detection/

Answer (score 0):

Try the code from [Redrome.com](http://redrome.com). They show how to load the page properly.